# Is there any keyboard shortcut to Force Quit all applications?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any apple Keyboard Shortcut to force quitting all of my applications?

I really need this sometimes because i have a old MacBook Air and it freezes if I put more than 14 applications. I just want to ask if there are any KeyBoard shortcuts to force quitting all of the applications using the Apple KeyBoard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a script... or you could hit CMD+Tab and while holding CMD hit "q" over and over. It will cycle through your apps and quit them one by one pretty quickly.

Comment: No problem! It is a handy trick to know about!

Answer (score 1):

Kind of, but it will require some mouse clicks.

```
CMD+Alt+Esc
```

That will pop up the "Force Quit Applications window.  Shift-click the last item so that they are all highlighted and then press "Force Quit".  It will ask you to confirm by clicking "Force Quit" again.

There are probably other ways you could do this with a single shortcut but they would require adding something to your Mac like a script or app.  For instance, you could write an Automater app to quit everything and then create a shortcut in the system preferences to launch the app.  I'm assuming you are asking how to do this on any Mac that is not modified with special programs or scripts.  Ask a new question for writing a script to do this, if that is what you want.

Comment: After bringing up the *Force Quit Applications Window* you **can** navigate through items with the *Up* and *Down* arrows, and hit *Enter* to force quit them. To select more than one item, you can press *Shift* while doing *Up / Down* and then force-quit **all** of the selected applications by hitting *Enter*.

Answer (score 1):

This terminates the applications that are included in the force quit window, Dock, and application switcher:

`kill $(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to unix id of processes where background only is false'|tr -d ,)`

Answer (score 1):

Press Command + Option + Esc keys together at the same time. Then a window will pop up. Select the application you want to close.